# Sharepoint 2007 Custom List Templates

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Hi  I am wanting to create a little tutorial on how to create a webpart that I have added to one of the website's I have created.

I know that there is the List Templates gallery in which I could use to give this part as a file however I am using Site Columns.

Due to this will this cause errors when importing to a new Site?

Will the user need to create the Site Columns previously and will they automatically be used once importing my Custom List file?

or will when it is imported the column appear?

I don't currently have another site to test this on as yet so was wondering if anyone here already knew the answer for this?

Any light that can be shed on this question is very much appreciated and thanks in advance as well =]

Answer (score 1):

I am totally confused by your question. How are List Templates gallery and a custom webpart related ?

Probably you meant site Template Gallery ?

```
What you need to do is :  
- Create a solution package
- Create two features - one for your custom columns and custom webpart
- Optionally create a list template feature to define the columns in the list.
```

Comment: Basically the CQWP is going to need certain columns however the columns are not ones that are "out-of-the-box" they have been created for the CQWP.

Comment: Yes, then you need a feature to deploy those columns

Comment: Oh right I see if the user creates the individual site columns before the list is imported will the columns be automatically used?

Answer (score 0):

If this is truly a list template (you created it by going into List Settings and selecting Save As Template), then the site columns, content type, and list schema should all be contained in the manifest.xml file inside the stp file. You should not need to create anything manually to generate a list based on a template uploaded to the List Templates Gallery.

If this is a list definition feature, then you should create features that define the site columns, content type, and the list definition. The users can manually create site columns that match on name, type, and just about every other attribute, except the one that matters most - ID. Each time a site column is created in the browser, it will be assigned a different ID. That ID will not match what you have defined in your list definition.

Comment: It is through the List Settings & Save as template; but I was unsure whether or not the columns would become "Site Columns" or if they are going to be only attached to the List as I will need to filter by these new columns

Comment: I'm not exactly sure myself. Everything you need to create a list should be in the stp file. But I don't remember seeing custom columns from the stp file appear in Site Columns. Even still, you should be able to filter by these columns since they should share the same name, internal name, and ID.